# How can I create an NPM repository containing a package and its dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a system that is offline that I need to airdrop a couple of npm packages into, including their dependencies. I've tried several solutions for picking an npm package and packaging up it and all of its dependencies into a tarball to be transferred to the offline system, but none even come close to working thus far. A quick effective solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the most obvious thing?

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir drop
cd drop
npm i $1
cd ..
tar -zcvf drop.tar.gz drop
```

Comment: Why does everything have to be laced with sarcasm? These aren't complete instructions.

Comment: It's not sarcasm.  It's a script.  Didn't seem like you needed something more complicated so not sure why you say it's incomplete.

Comment: People don't ask questions because it was obvious to them. In any case, what's the procedure for unpacking on the receiving end so that the dependencies are picked up by applications that depend on node deps when they run.

Comment: tar -xzf drop.tar.gz

Comment: I have copied the contents of the directory to /usr/local/lib/node_modules, /usr/lib/nodejs and I have also ran the application in question from within the node_modules userspace directory, to no avail. So still not seeing what's obvious about this.

Comment: So the problem is you are trying to deploy and the app says it can't load a module? Make sure you include the package.json and the main is file and then node_modules is a subdirectory. Can you edit your question to mention the error you get when you run your app?

Comment: Also you don't want to run from inside  node_modules you want to run the app from the parent of that dir.

Answer (score 0):

After comprehensively trying every top solution recommended by Google, I eventually discovered npmbox, which works like a charm.

https://github.com/arei/npmbox

A bit of useful guidance when interacting with the node community, whether in #node.js on freenode or here on StackOverflow:  https://blog.npmjs.org/post/163421115230/shutting-down-npm-irc

There is a general pattern of not reading questions carefully and putting down the person answering them. Just ignore those folks.

Comment: I never put you down and I read your question and comments carefully.

Comment: Apparently npm5 breaks this functionality, any workarounds?